# Symbol could not be resolved eclipse CDT

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

It's a common question on stack overflow, but my case is strange and I couldn't find appropriate answers so I'm still posting it.

It's a large project but only five file included for this problem: types.h, glob.h, test.c, test.h and main.c

in **types.h** say I define a struct:

```
struct s_foo {
    int a;
};
```

in **glob.h**

```
struct s_foo *foo;
```

in **test.h**

```
#ifndef GLOB_H
#define GLOB_H
extern struct s_foo *foo;
#endif
```

in **test.c**

```
#include "types.h"
#include "test.h"
struct s_foo *foo = NULL;
```

in **main.c**

```
#include "types.h"
#include "test.h"
...
foo = (struct s_foo *)malloc(sizeof(struct s_foo));
```

The program is compilable by gcc and running fine, but eclipse is giving me this annoying error in main.c that symbol 'foo' could not be resolved.

Anyone can tell me why eclipse is giving me this error? Is this because multiple definition of variable foo?

Thanks!

Comment: Just a hint: it's not good practice to define a variable in a header file. This is 'multiple definition' error prone.

Comment: It is defined in "glob.h", and now the problem is symbol cannot resolved. I was wondering if eclipse cannot determine whether foo is defined in test.h or glob.h so it gives symbol cannot resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure eclipse can see all your .h files. For me it seems it is not including all relevant .h files.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on Eclipse for code ported from Visual Studio 2013. My best guess is the compiler could not do proper multiple times of symbol scan. So my final solution is add one more declaration in a file where the error appears. For your case, I suggest you add

extern struct s_foo *foo;

before error statement in file main.c